# Wordpress - Add label on top of custom inline form fields

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm using the `show_user_profile` and the `edit_user_profile` to display custom profile fields in my wordpress backend. I need to be able to have a label on top of each form field I have and to have some of them inline so I've writed this code to have inline form fields

```html
                    <h4>Cluster</h4>
                    <span>
                        <input type="text" name="cluster_lv1" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta('cluster_lv1', $user->ID) ); ?>">
                        <input type="text" name="cluster_lv2" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta('cluster_lv2', $user->ID) ); ?>">
                        <input type="text" name="cluster_lv3" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta('cluster_lv3', $user->ID) ); ?>">
                    </span>
```

I've tried to add a label using the `<label>` tag but it will be displayed on the left side of each form field and this isn't what I need. Since there isn't any reference to know how WordPress assign classes for admin pages, how I can achive my scope and add labels on top of form fields correctly?

At the moment form fields appear like the image, and it's difficult to distinguish them without labels on top of them.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've edited the question to be more clear about the needing